# Understanding mod_rewrite syntax

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I write in `.htaccess` this mod_rewrite

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.my_extension$ $1.php
```

and open url: `site.com/index.my_extension` this wroks fine, opened `index.php`

But when I am trying mod_rewrite like this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

this gives me `Internal Server Error`.

Why this happened? what is reason?

Comment: You need to add more information. Have you enabled rewrite logging? Are the two rewrite rules in the same config file? It can be possible that you could have a redirect/rewrite loop, as you are catching all then redirecting to index.php?url=foo/bar/index.php?url=foo/bar/index.php, etc.

Comment: 1)  `Have you enabled rewrite logging?` --- if  rewrite logging not enabled, then how firts rewriterule works?  

2)  `Are the two rewrite rules in the same config file?`  --- no, just one RewriteRule is in `.htaccess` file.

3) `It can be possible that you could have a redirect/rewrite loop` --- In other servers, catching all then redirecting to index.php works, and here why must happened redirect/rewrite loop? reason of this may be some option?

Comment: read this: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

You have a redirect loop, you need to exclude index.php from the rules.